# In javascript/ jquery adding a google calendar without // in the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, comments, google-calendar-api

I have a Google Calendar iframe and want to store it in JS. When I call it I want it to appear but the link has a `//` in it. How do I get the `//` to appear and not comment out the entire line?

```
var info = {
    calendar: "<iframe src="https: //www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showDate=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=275&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=v3jgra0nq7c0ohru1itke2us3g%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%232F6309&amp;ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles" style=" border-width:0 " width="420" height="275" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>"/*html stuff*/,
}
```

Comment: here is the code    var info ={ calender: "<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showDate=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=275&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=v3jgra0nq7c0ohru1itke2us3g%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%232F6309&amp;ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles" style=" border-width:0 " width="420" height="275" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>"/*html stuff*/,}

Comment: Please edit your question to add further information instead of posting in the comments. Also, try to format your code for better understanding. Refer to the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should EDIT your question and put the code in there.  Use 4 spaces indent in front of all the lines that have code.  This will give the proper formatting so that we can see what is going on.

As for // ruining your link, this really should not happen if your string content is in double quotes as it should be.  For example,

```
var info="<iframe src=\"https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showDate=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=275&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=v3jgra0nq7c0ohru1itke2us3g%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%232F6309&amp;ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles%22\" />"
```

Notice that I had to ESCAPE the double quotes within the string so that javascript knew I wasn't finished with my string

\"